# Overlay intersect in attribute form

Tags: qgis, qfield

I use the following expression (array_to_string(overlay_intersects('layer name',"Field name")) to get the field data from another layer that intersects with a new layer that will be created. However, it results NULL value, and it causes an error when opened and used in QField 3.1.9 Borneo (but it works fine in QField 3.0.7 Amazonia).

Is there any other expression to do the same?

[image]

Comment: It is not the QGIS version, it is QField and 3.1.9 Borneo is the most recent one

Comment: Hi, I am using QGIS 3.34. the 3.0 / 3.1 is the version of QField

Answer (score 3):

You can try an aggregate function instead, which will lead to the same results. It will have the following structure in your case:

```
array_to_string(aggregate(layer:='Manuring block',
      aggregate:='array_agg',
      expression:="Blk_No",
      filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))))
```

But I did not test it with QField...